# How can I run an algorithm over a list in Python and store the results in a list?

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy

The algorithm shown in the code below calculates the Chebyshev spatial distance between an ellipsoid image drawn in Python by the `ellipse` function and another black and white image.

[image: a busy cat]

`translate` is a function which moves each point of the ellipsoid by a certain distance. I would like to observe how the Chebyshev distance varies with different translation values. I have a list containing the pairs of translation coordinates I would like to try out:

```py
translation_points = 
[ (5, 6), (5, 7), (5, 8), (5, 9), (5, 10), (5, 11), (5, 12), (5, 13), (5, 14), (6, 5), (6, 6), (6, 7), (6, 8), (6, 9), (6, 10), (6, 11), (6, 12), (6, 13), (6, 14), (7, 5), (7, 6), (7, 7), (7, 8), (7, 9), (7, 10), (7, 11), (7, 12), (7, 13), (7, 14), (8, 5), (8, 6), (8, 7), (8, 8), (8, 9), (8, 10), (8, 11), (8, 12), (8, 13), (8, 14), (9, 5), (9, 6), (9, 7), (9, 8), (9, 9), (9, 10), (9, 11), (9, 12), (9, 13), (9, 14), (10, 5), (10, 6), (10, 7), (10, 8), (10, 9), (10, 10), (10, 11), (10, 12), (10, 13), (10, 14), (11, 5), (11, 6), (11, 7), (11, 8), (11, 9), (11, 10), (11, 11), (11, 12), (11, 13), (11, 14), (12, 5), (12, 6), (12, 7), (12, 8), (12, 9), (12, 10), (12, 11), (12, 12), (12, 13), (12, 14), (13, 5), (13, 6), (13, 7), (13, 8), (13, 9), (13, 10), (13, 11), (13, 12), (13, 13), (13, 14), (14, 5), (14, 6), (14, 7), (14, 8), (14, 9), (14, 10), (14, 11), (14, 12), (14, 13), (14, 14)]
```

As seen in `translate` below, I predefine my `DX` and `DY` to be `(5,5)`. I want to change the values of `DX` and `DY` to those above (in `translation_points`) and store the resulting spatial distances in a list. How can I update my code to pass in the list to the algorithm and output a list?

Here is my existing code for the algorithm:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from scipy.spatial import distance
import scipy.misc
im = scipy.misc.imread(r'Downloads/irregular1.png', flatten=False, mode='L')


def ellipse(x, y):
    value = (x*x) + (y*y)/3
    if (value >= 600):
        return 0
    else:
        return 1

def translate(x, y):
    DX = 5
    DY = 5
    return (x- DX, y - DY)

def rotate(x, y):
    theta = np.radians(45)
    matrix = np.array([[np.cos(theta), -np.sin(theta)], [np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta)]])
    return np.dot(matrix, (x,y))

data = np.zeros((100,100))

for i in range(0, 100):
    for j in range(0, 100):
        (x, y) = translate(i,j)
        (x, y) = rotate(x, y)
        data[i,j] = ellipse(x, y)

plt.imshow(data, cmap="gray")
#plt.show()


plt.imshow(im)
#plt.show()

counter = 0 #tracking white
counter1 = 0 #tracking black 

#getting the dimensions of the image -> y
yDim = im.shape[0]

#getting the dimensions of the image -> x
xDim = im.shape[1]

for i in range(yDim):
    for j in range (xDim): 
        if np.any(im[i,j]) == 0:
            counter += 1
        else: 
            counter1 += 1

#initialize empty array this array will receive all the white pixels 
a = np.empty([100,100])

for i in range(yDim):
    for j in range (xDim): 
        if np.any(im[i,j]) == 0:
            np.append(a,im[i,j],axis=None)

#spatial distance 
a = a.flatten()
data = data.flatten()

distance = distance.hamming(a,data))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated to show two ways to do it. The first way is to have it in the function shown below. Make a list to temporarily store the results `temp`, loop through the list `translation_points` that is defined in the function, subtract the difference and add it to our temporary list `temp`. Once its looped all the way through the list `translation_points` return the temp storing all the new points.

```
def translate(x, y):
    translation_points = [ (5, 6), (5, 7), (5, 8), (5, 9), (5, 10), (5, 11), (5, 12), (5, 13), (5, 14), (6, 5), (6, 6), (6, 7), (6, 8), (6, 9), (6, 10), (6, 11), (6, 12), (6, 13), (6, 14), (7, 5), (7, 6), (7, 7), (7, 8), (7, 9), (7, 10), (7, 11), (7, 12), (7, 13), (7, 14), (8, 5), (8, 6), (8, 7), (8, 8), (8, 9), (8, 10), (8, 11), (8, 12), (8, 13), (8, 14), (9, 5), (9, 6), (9, 7), (9, 8), (9, 9), (9, 10), (9, 11), (9, 12), (9, 13), (9, 14), (10, 5), (10, 6), (10, 7), (10, 8), (10, 9), (10, 10), (10, 11), (10, 12), (10, 13), (10, 14), (11, 5), (11, 6), (11, 7), (11, 8), (11, 9), (11, 10), (11, 11), (11, 12), (11, 13), (11, 14), (12, 5), (12, 6), (12, 7), (12, 8), (12, 9), (12, 10), (12, 11), (12, 12), (12, 13), (12, 14), (13, 5), (13, 6), (13, 7), (13, 8), (13, 9), (13, 10), (13, 11), (13, 12), (13, 13), (13, 14), (14, 5), (14, 6), (14, 7), (14, 8), (14, 9), (14, 10), (14, 11), (14, 12), (14, 13), (14, 14)]
    temp = []
    for i in translation_points:
        temp.append((x-i[0],y-i[1]))
    return temp

print(translate(5,5))
```

The other way is to feed in the list of tuples as an argument and do the same procedure. Can offer more functionality this way by being able to change the translation_points.

```
translation_points = [ (5, 6), (5, 7), (5, 8), (5, 9), (5, 10), (5, 11), (5, 12), (5, 13), (5, 14), (6, 5), (6, 6), (6, 7), (6, 8), (6, 9), (6, 10), (6, 11), (6, 12), (6, 13), (6, 14), (7, 5), (7, 6), (7, 7), (7, 8), (7, 9), (7, 10), (7, 11), (7, 12), (7, 13), (7, 14), (8, 5), (8, 6), (8, 7), (8, 8), (8, 9), (8, 10), (8, 11), (8, 12), (8, 13), (8, 14), (9, 5), (9, 6), (9, 7), (9, 8), (9, 9), (9, 10), (9, 11), (9, 12), (9, 13), (9, 14), (10, 5), (10, 6), (10, 7), (10, 8), (10, 9), (10, 10), (10, 11), (10, 12), (10, 13), (10, 14), (11, 5), (11, 6), (11, 7), (11, 8), (11, 9), (11, 10), (11, 11), (11, 12), (11, 13), (11, 14), (12, 5), (12, 6), (12, 7), (12, 8), (12, 9), (12, 10), (12, 11), (12, 12), (12, 13), (12, 14), (13, 5), (13, 6), (13, 7), (13, 8), (13, 9), (13, 10), (13, 11), (13, 12), (13, 13), (13, 14), (14, 5), (14, 6), (14, 7), (14, 8), (14, 9), (14, 10), (14, 11), (14, 12), (14, 13), (14, 14)]

def translate(x,y,l): 
    temp = []
    for i in l:
        temp.append((x-i[0],y-i[1]))
    return temp
```

Comment: could you please show me how to do it the other way you suggested?

Comment: the function itself works, but together with the rest of the code I get an error 'too many values to unpack (expected 2)'

Comment: I think that's a whole separate question, the functions works as designed. To give you a hint though generally that error occurs when trying to assign multiple variables from a list and not having enough variables.